# xpath in =importXML() for extracting meta descriptions

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, seo

I'm trying to use Xpath to pull in the meta descriptions from web pages, using Google Sheets.

I have this working to pull in the titles:  `=importXml(www.example.com; "//title")`

Here are two sources of my learning:

http://seogadget.co.uk/playing-around-with-importxml-in-google-spreadsheets/
http://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=75507

I have read many other posts on this site, and this seems to be the similar idea of what I want:

```
"/html/head/meta[@name='description']/@content"
"/*/head/meta[@name='description']/@content"
"//head/meta[@name=\"description\"]/@content"
```

None of these work in Google Sheets, which specifies to write it in Xpath.  The only difference, is that in Google Sheets you are to use ' in place of "  (hence why description is like that).  I've honestly tried it about 219 different ways....no luck.

Any ideas?  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes problem could be related with Apostrophes (’), Inverted commas single (‘x’) or double ("x") (aka quotation marks, speech marks, quotes), spreadsheet localle and formula syntax, see difference `"/*/head/meta[@name='description']/@content"` vs `'/*/head/meta[@name="description"]/@content'` if you use it in the formula, generally I'm always testing not in the formula, but in separate cell (to avoid colissions).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
//meta[@name='description']/@content
```

So your full URL call in google sheet would be

```
=importxml(A1,"//meta[@name='description']/@content")
```

I've built some awesome SEO tools using importXML - this is just the start of it mate! :)