# ImportXML xpath to google sheets returning #N/A

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, xml-parsing

I am a beginner to programming in general and google in particular. I've been trying to get this (what seems to me) simple web query working for a while using the importxml() function. I am trying to pull a reference from a citation generation website, where you search a pubmed ID number (PMID).

The site is https://mickschroeder.com/citation/?q=18515037 where 18515037 is the PMID. This brings up a citation.

```
Allison MA, Kwan K, Ditomasso D, Wright CM, Criqui MH. The epidemiology of
abdominal aortic diameter. J Vasc Surg. 2008;48(1):121-7.
```

I did inspect element and got the XPath as:

```
//*[@id="citation_formatted"]/text()
```

So i have tried

```
=importxml(ttps://mickschroeder.com/citation/?q=18515037, "//*[@id="citation_formatted"]/text()")
```

And it returns #N/A or blank. I've tried taking out the * but can't get it working. Do I need to escape the () in the text()? Or do I have the Xpath totally wrong. I did a search for the answer but I figure I'm so new I can't apply those concepts.

Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6052472/xpath-google-sheets-importxml?rq=1